# Group By and take first and last elements from the table in c# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

I have a table called Invoices. I have to group by createdDate and take the first and last invoice number and show it as range. Along with this,i need to select the createdDate as one of the columns too.  I am using entity frame work and below is the code I have tried before. I am a beginner and it would be great if you can give me the correct solution.

```
MyContext.Invoices
         .Where(x => x.IsActive == true)
         .GroupBy( t=>
         {
            CreatedDate = DbFunctions.TruncateTime(t.CreationDate),
            InvoiceNumber = t.InvoiceNumber
         })
         .ToList()
         .Select(t => new ReportViewModel
         {
            DayDate = t.Key.CreatedDate.ToString(),
            TotalAmount = t.Sum(x => x.Price),
            InvoiceNumRange = t.Key.InvoiceNumber.First() + " - " + t.Key.InvoiceNumber.Last(),
            DisplayLabel = t.Key.CreatedDate.ToString()                              
         })
         .Where(d => (DateTime.Parse(d.DayDate) >= fromDate && DateTime.Parse(d.DayDate) <=  toDate))
         .OrderByDescending(o => o.DayDate)
         .ToList()
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all: don't do an intermediate ToList. This will execute the query and fetch all data. Later you throw away some of the fetched data. Let the database do all selecting that it can do, move only the data to your local process that is needed, and as last statement do the ToList.

We don't need complete Invoices, only some values.

```
DateTime fromDate = ...
DateTime toDate = ...

var result = myContext.Invoices.Select(invoice => new
{
    CreatedDate = DbFunctions.TruncateTime(invoice.CreationDate),
    IsActive = invoice.IsActive,
    InvoiceNumber = invoice.InvoiceNumber,
    Price = invoice.Price,
})
```

Keep only the active items that are within date range:

```
.Where(invoice => invoice.IsActive
               && fromDate <= invoice.CreatedDate
               && toDdate >= invoice.CreaedDate)
```

From the remaining items, make groups of with same value of `CreatedDate`.
Use the overload of `IQueryable.GroupBy` that has a parameter resultSelector.

I'm not sure if entity framework knows the String Handling methods, so I'll select the needed data as DateTime, before transferring it to local memory.

```
.GroupBy(invoice => invoice.CreatedDate,       // groups with same value for CreatedDate

// parameter resultSelector: take the createdDate, 
// and all invoices that have this createdDate to make one new ReportViewModel
(createdDate, invoicesWithThisCreatedDate) => new
{
    DayDate = createdDate,
    TotalAmount = invoicesWithThisCreatedDate.Select(invoice => invoice.Price).Sum(),
    FirstInvoiceNumber = invoicesWithThisCreatedDate
                         .Select(invoice => invoice.InvoiceNumber)
                         .Min(),
    LastInvoiceNumber = invoicesWithThisCreatedDate
                         .Select(invoice => invoice.InvoiceNumber)
                         .Max(),
    })
```

I assumed that `InvoiceNumber` is a number. If not, you can't use `Min` and `Max`, you'll have to `OrderBy` / `OrderByDescending` and take the first element.

Now that you've limited the data to the minimum, you can move the remaining data to your local process:

```
.AsEnumerable()
```

Now that it is in your local process, you can use the string handling methods and other local methods:

```
.Select(fetchedItem => new ReportViewModel
{
    DayDate = fetchedItem.CreatedDate.ToString(),
    TotalAmount = fetchedItem.TotalAmount,
    InvoiceNumRange = String.Format("{0} - {1}", fetchedItem.FirstInvoiceNumber,
                                                 fetchedItem.LastInvoiceNumber),

    DisplayLabel = fetchedItem.CreatedDate.ToString(),
})
```

And finally: execute it all:

```
.ToList();
```